# Customizing cursor in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cursor, interactive

In Matlab 2012a I have generated a figure from a previous code that is SSI as a function of age.
I want to customize datatip by updating my own function instead of the default one. I know how to change x and y and now I have Age and SSI for them. However, I have another piece of information -subjectID- which I want to add to the display text.
By clicking on each point, I want datatip to show Age, SSI and subject ID of corresponding data point.
This is what I have now:
matlab is a saved work place of my SSI-age.

```
function output_txt = myupdatefcn(obj,event_obj,...
                  matlab,labels,SubjectID)
pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
x = pos(1); 
y = pos(2);
[~, ~, raw0_0] = xlsread('Data.xlsx','CONTROLS','A2:A106');
raw = [raw0_0];
SubjectID = cell2mat(raw);
output_txt = {['AGE: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['SSI: ',num2str(pos(2),4)],...
    ['SubjectID: ',SubjectID]};
idx = find(matlab == x,1);  
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(matlab),idx);
output_txt{end+1} = cell2mat(labels(row));
```

Obviously, this is not right. Can somebody please help me out here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, I make the following assumptions (which may be incorrect):
* the subjectID is a cell containing a vector of strings
* subjectID is `X` position of the clicked point

#### First, a quick digression: getting SubjectID into your plot

I noticed, in your function call, you have SubjectID as one of the input parameters.  However, it appears that it would never be used, since the next line that uses it assigns it a value.
As written, this will read from the excel file each and every time that the update function is called.  You might wish to move the load-from-excel portion into the same section of code where the data is first loaded.  If I assume the SubjectID is text, you can store it in the UserData variable of the timeseries.  That would make the following work:

#### Onward to the answer

So, if you include your SubjectID information in the userdata, when you first plot like so:

```
% ...not shown: get the ages, SSIs and SubjectIDs ....

plot(ages, SSIs, 'UserData', SubjectIDs);   % Store SubjectIDs along with the line...
```

Then the following should work -- or at least put you on solid ground.

```
function output_txt = myupdatefcn(obj,event_obj)   
  pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
  x = pos(1); 
  y = pos(2);
  allIDs = get(event_obj.Target,'UserData');
  thisSubject = event_obj.UserData{pos(1)};

  output_txt = {['AGE: ',num2str(pos(1),4)],...
    ['SSI: ',num2str(pos(2),4)],...
    ['SubjectID: ',thisSubject]};
```

You can probably get rid of the last 3 lines of code, since you know a priori that all 3 values are accessible.

Hope that helps.